# Is it possible to display the webpage inside a Adaptive Card/any other card in Power Virtual Agent through Bot Framework Composer?

Tags: json, botframework, power-automate, bot-framework-composer, power-virtual-agents

I have a doubt regarding whether it is possible to display a webpage inside the Cards using Bot Framework Composer in Power Virtual Agent.

I have tried but I am able to create using Action.OpenUrl and a Button but not able to display whole page/particular info inside the card.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to render a website in an adaptive card.
So, if you need to show particular info in a card, my suggestion would be to get it from the website (scraping/API) and show in in the card via templating

[more info on templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/)